# iOS Style Buttons in share sheet

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

[image]

Is there anyway to style the buttons for the Mail sheet created from a `UIActivityViewController`

Share screen is called via this code

```
-(void)shareLink:(id)sender{

Post *post = [self.linkViewItems objectAtIndex:self.swipedPath.row];

NSMutableString *txt = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[txt appendString:[post description]];
[txt appendString:@"  "];
[txt appendString:[post href]];

NSString* someText = txt;
NSArray* dataToShare = @[someText];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];

}
```

Comment: try subclassing MFMailComposeViewController

Answer (score -1):

try with this

```
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;


        [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];//You can set your colour
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bg_header.png"];
        UIImageView * iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,42)];
        iv.image = image1;
        iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [[[picker viewControllers] lastObject] navigationItem].titleView = iv;
        [[picker navigationBar] sendSubviewToBack:iv];
        [iv release];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
        [picker release];
```

see this for inbuilt frame work.

[Override UIActivityViewController default behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769499/override-uiactivityviewcontroller-default-behaviour)

Comment: thanks, I think. I'm not creating this window my self though, it appears after selecting 'mail' from the UIActivityViewController , where would I put this code?

Comment: write this on button click

Comment: but as I said, I'm not dealing with the button click, it's come from UIActivityViewController, can you not use the appeareanceWhenContainedIn proxy somehow?

Comment: I'm not, I'm using UIActivityViewController

Comment: yes, but you have to Override UIActivityViewController behaviour. oR write my code with one button click.