# UIActivityViewController - Mail Activity - How to set email recipients and subject?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, email, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set recipients for UIActivityViewController in iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623260/how-do-i-set-recipients-for-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-ios-6)

Is there anyway to set the Subject and/or the email recipients for a mail message when using `UIActivityViewController`?

I am able to make a successful message, but can't figure out how to set a Subject or set the mail recipients.