# UIActivityController Set "To"

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have tried this for setting the subject in the UIActivityController, but can anyone tell me how to set "To"?
To whom we want to send the mail?
I want to send the mail to the pepticular person only thats why I need to set "To".
Thanks in advance.

```
UIActivityViewController* avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
    initWithActivityItems:@[@"share items"]  applicationActivities:nil];

    [avc setValue:@"your subject" forKey:@"subject"];

    avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        // ...
    };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set recipients for UIActivityViewController in iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623260/how-do-i-set-recipients-for-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-ios-6)