# How to use ActionSheetIOS attaching email TO

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using `ActionSheetIOS` to let user open his personal Email client on iOS. Unfortunately I do not know how to populate the recipient (`to` part) of the email.
I didn't find anything in the RN documentation.

Any help?

Comment: I don't think it's possible: http://www.openradar.me/14344842, http://www.openradar.me/12393854. There is a way to Swizzle around it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623260/how-do-i-set-recipients-for-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-ios-6

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately I saw that it is impossible, and that's why I will try another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as some guys confirmed that this thing is impossible, I think I will go for this other way: https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail

Answer (score 1):

You could try opening the mail client with [Linking.openURL()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) and a [mailto:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) link.

something like: `Linking.openURL('mailto:example@domain.com?subject=example&body=example').catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err)`.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. I already used the `openURL`, but I prefer to use the `ActionSheetIOS` component so the user can choose which client mail to use

Comment: makes sense... I can't think of any other way to do this with ActionSheet though :(

Comment: Thank you anyway. I hope in a new idea